# How can I choose where the error message from the validator `required` appear?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, message

How can I choose where the error message from the validator `required` appear?
The error message is now displayed at the bottom of my page but I want it next to my inputbox.

```
<p>Firstname: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.firstname}" required="true"/></p>
<p>Lastname: <h:inputText value="#{userBean.lastname}" required="true"/></p>
```

Comment: I think you may need something like <h:message for="id_of_input_field" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those appearing at the bottom are actually unhandled messages which will only appear when the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is been set to `Development` in `web.xml`.

You need a `<h:message>` to declare the location where the message should be shown. Further, you also need a `<h:outputLabel>` to represent the labels (which has semantic and usability advantages).

Here's the complete set:

```html
<p>
    <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname:"/>
    <h:inputText id="firstname" label="Firstname" value="#{userBean.firstname}" required="true"/>
    <h:message for="firstname" />
</p>
<p>
    <h:outputLabel for="lastname" value="Lastname:"/>
    <h:inputText id="lastname" label="Lastname" value="#{userBean.lastname}" required="true"/>
    <h:message for="lastname" />
</p>
```